# Is the Solar System Described in a Psalm?

Tags: science, verse-identification

Is there a Psalm that seems to describe the Solar System and that everything revolves around the Sun?

Comment: Usually, "verse search" questions like this will be closed as off-topic.  It would help if you include some information on the research you tried to find an answer on your own.  (If you haven't done any yet, there are a lot of online search tools (e.g. biblegateway.com) that will let you search  for a particular word or subject.)

Comment: With confidence I can say you will not find such a verse because that is not the cosmology of the Bible. Also the Bible often speaks of a moving sun and never mentions a moving earth. The Bible also never mentions planets, wandering stars are still stars and not planets. You will be imposing a modern understanding on an ancient text that makes for poor hermeneutics if you reinterpret the text to mean planets.

Comment: You might have better luck asking if there are any Christians who use the Bible to prove a heliocentric for the solar system and then, if there's anything in Psalms (or the rest of the Bible) it is indubitable that that will be included in the answer.  As such, JDM is right, verse search questions aren't appropriate for this site because of the multifarious ways we interpret scripture.

Answer (score 3):

No, but there is a Psalm that was apparently used to posit a *geocentric* vision of the universe instead of a heliocentric one.

> He set the earth on its foundations; it can never be moved.
>
> Psalm 104:5 - NIV

or also, in the Catholic Bible (and others):

> You fixed the earth on its foundation, so it can never be shaken.
>
> Psalm 104:5 - NABRE

Which is a little less explicit. But still contradicted by earthquakes, which [aren't unknown in the Holy Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earthquakes_in_the_Levant)

But the Bible, especially Genesis, is full of imagery that isn't scientific and wasn't meant to be so.

If you truly were looking for a verse that could be used to support the Earth revolving around the sun for a scientific reason, I think most Christians you meet would tell you that's not a fruitful experience.  But if you weren't just simply mistaken and this wasn't the answer you're looking for, let me know and I'll delete this post - maybe someone else knows what you're talking about!

Comment: A superficial local earthquake is not a shaking of the plane of the world on its foundations. So no contradiction that I can see.

Comment: *Used* being the key word.

Comment: It may come as a surprise but is still used @curiousdannii

Comment: @autodidact I was being a little facetious, but you bring up a good point - how bad would an Earthquake have to be for 3rd century BC Jews to say "wow, this really contradicts what David said about the Earth and its foundations"?

Comment: It would have to be worldwide, that would be my guess, lands and oceans

Answer (score 2):

Below are some verses from the Psalms that mention the sun, the moon and the stars:

> When I consider your heavens, the work of your fingers, the moon and the stars, which you have set in place, what is man that you are mindful of him, the son of man that you care for him?...O Lord, our Lord, how majestic is your name in all the earth! (Psalm 8:3-4, 9).
>
> The heavens declare the glory of God, and the sky above proclaims his handiwork...  Their voice goes out through all the earth, and their words to the end of the world.  In them he has set a tent for the sun, which comes out like a bridegroom leaving his chamber, and, like a strong man, runs its course with joy. Its rising is from the end of the heavens, and its circuit to the end of them, and there is nothing hidden from its heat (Psalm 19:1; 4-6).
>
> He counts the number of the stars, He calls them all by name (Psalm 147:4).

The Bible mentions three constellations: Orion, the Bear (Ursa Major), and “the crooked serpent” (most likely Draco) in Job 9:9; 26:13; 38:31-32; and Amos 5:8.  The same passages also reference the star group Pleiades (the Seven Stars).  God is the One Who “fastens the bands” of these constellations; He is the One who brings them forth, “each in its season.”

The Psalms simply give credit to God for the creation of the heavens and the earth, and of the stars that are visible to the naked eye.  Psalm 104:5 says that God “set the earth on its foundations, so that it should never be moved” but it would be quite wrong to imply that means our solar system revolves around the sun.

> Taken in order, Genesis 1:14-18, Psalm 104:5, Job 26:7 and Isaiah 40:22 were often cited to support the geocentric theory of Ptolemaeus. Yet none of these Scriptures, taken in any order whatsoever, state that God designed the universe with Earth at its center. In fact, Earth isn’t even the center of its own small solar system; the sun is. We can understand why Copernicus and, later, Galileo, who posited the sun-centered (heliocentric) theory, caused such a controversy in the church. It was thought that heliocentricism contradicted the biblical teaching of geocentrism. But, again, the problem was that God’s Word doesn’t say that the Earth is at the center of anything. - [Does the Bible teach geocentrism?](https://www.gotquestions.org/geocentrism-Bible.html)

Comment: @Autodidact if someone can't hear what you're saying in the comments, please take it to chat (the chat room is pretty dead so you'd be more than welcome to start this thread up there) but please don't post 3 comments in a row full of text, that's obviously not what comments are designed for and antagonizes answerers more than clarifies thought.